# Form login data is not sent in IE 11, Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, authentication, token, laravel-5.4

I am working on a project with Laravel 5.4, when testing login in IE 11 browser I have an error related to missing the parameter (TokenMismatchException).
I debugged the data before reaching the final destination, and checked that no data arrived (+ request: ParameterBag).
IE 11: 
[image]Other browsers are OK:
[image]
Error in IE:
[image]
Does anyone have an idea of ​​what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: is this behavior reproducible?

Comment: This might be related to the cookie expiration. Is your server time accurate?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2962) check the comment of @divostar `Here is my implementation. ....` !!

Comment: Yes, my development server is centos and apache, the date is synchronized and in agreement.

I also implemented the solution indicated by my friend @divostar, but with no positive result.

We do not make changes to the source code of the framework, only implementations within the scope of the project.